# What is the meaning of leaden knell? This is from novel 1984

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

The face of Big Brother swam into his mind, displacing that of O’Brien. Just as he had done a few days earlier, he slid a coin out of his pocket and looked at it. The face gazed up at him, heavy, calm, protecting: but what kind of smile was hidden beneath the dark moustache? Like a leaden knell the words came back at him

Comment: Hello Siddharth, This question can be on topic here, as you are using the novel to learn English.  But you may get better and more expert answers on interpretation of literature at [literature.se]

Answer (score 1):

"Knell" is the sound of a bell ringing. "Leaden" means heavy, like lead. So the simile is that the words came to him like the heavy sound of a bell.